# How to turn on numbers on the first pages of my sections?

Tags: header-footer, templates

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,times,numbered,print,index, oneside]{Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}
\include{Abstract/abstract}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\printnomenclature

\mainmatter

my text
\end{document}
```

So the structure of my document is the following:

> 1. The title page (treated as the first one in roman numbers, but the number isn't displayed).
> 2. The table of contets, abstract, etc. (not the main part of my thesis)- numbered using roman numbers.
> 3. My main thesis-numbered using arabic numbers.

I'd like to have a roman number on each page of the second part of my text. However, roman numbers aren't displayed on the page if this is the first page of a section (i.e. the abstract or the list of figures).

How can I diable this bevaviour? I'd like to have all my roman numbers (excpet for the title).

Comment: This depends on the document class -- your document isn't compilable, yet. What is the 2nd part of your text?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I'm using the a4paper class.

Comment: As far as I know there's no `a4paper` class -- that's a class option. And your example is still not compilable

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I'm sorry - I'm using this template: https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template/

Comment: Do you plan to provide this as a thesis to the Cambridge University? The empty page style is by class design, so this seems to be a demand of the thesis design!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, no, I don't. This is just a template that I liked when I was looking for a template for my thesis.

Comment: I see -- basically any command has this rubbish `\thispagestyle{empty}` specification, leaving empty pages then. It's a tedious work to get rid of them

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, are you sure? I removed this command and it didn't help. Maybe something else has a similar effect? Well, it works only for the dedication...

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to live risky, you can add the following after your title page.

> I cannot recommend that solution, though. It is against the design of the template. The author must have had some reasoning when coming up with that.

Basically, that replaces all instances of an empty page with a plain page. *All of them after you do this*.

```
\makeatletter
\let\ps@empty\ps@plain
\makeatother
```

Comment: That's what I had in mind too, but it's too risky!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer That is why i added the warning. The whole thing is buggy.

Comment: Could you explain to me why it is too risky and what the difference between a plain page and an empty page is?

Comment: @user2738748 plain page has page number, empty page not. Risky: there could be problems, that you can revert, but need a new solution for the problem above.

Comment: @Johannes_B, but why would there be a problem with your solution?

Comment: @user2738748 This is a very low level hacky solution. It has to be like that, since the template itself is quite hacky. You can use the solution, but i won't guarantee it working in every case.

Comment: @Johannes_B, it doesn't work for my template. Do you have any idea why? I added the command after *\end{titlepage}*.

Comment: @user2738748 The solution above works, but obviously not for *your* template. I don't know *your* template. Please update the question, or post a very new question on latex-community.org where you can upload a zip file.